# A question on $\sigma$-algebras on uncountable products of spaces.

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

When dealing with Borel $\sigma$-algebras, sooner or later, one comes across the fact that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots $ is a finite or infinite sequence of separable metrizable spaces. Then ${\cal B}(\prod_{n\in I} X_n) = \otimes_{n\in I} {\cal B}(X_n) $ if $\text{card}(I) \le \aleph_0. $

The proof is not too terrible either. I do not need it, but I got curious about what happens in the case of a product space like, say, $\mathbb{R}^T $ where $T $ is uncountable.

I wonder if the product $\sigma$-algebra equals the product of the $\sigma$-algebras here as well. I suspect it does not.  But I cannot find any convincing argument  to prove this claim. I have a feeling that, since nothing is countable, if one is to succeed, he or she will have to come up with a counter-example that involves simple sets like singletons, but that is where I stopped.

I would be very grateful if anyone could provide some clues on this issue. Thank you in advance for any kind reply.

Maurice

Comment: Try to make the following precise: Show that the set of all (Borel) subsets of $\Bbb{R}^T$ which only "depends" on countably many coordinates from $T$ forms a $\sigma$-algebra and contains the product sigma algebra. Use this to show that the product sigma algebra is a strict subset of the Borel sigma algebra. The hard part here is to make precise the notion of "depending" only on countably many coordinates.

Comment: Did it. Thank you. The countably many coordinates thing can be found in most textbook. Using the singletons in the product space, one proves that they are closed and hence must be in ${\cal B}(\prod_a X_a) $ but they are not in $\otimes_a {\cal B}(X_a). $